# What's wrong with this very simple mysql create table statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

```
create table foo(
id UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
barbaz VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8
)
```

[**Edit**]: OK I had accidentally removed the INT and I didn't realize it (these statements are generated automatically).[**/Edit**]

This gives me this error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
barbaz VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET '

Yeah, I'm using Maria DB as it replaces mysql in Fedora, but supposedly it's exactly the same syntax as Mysql.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you are not declaring the type of the `id` column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`UNSIGNED`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html) is not a type.  You need to specify the type (most likely `INT`):

```
id INT UNSIGNED ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been debugging stuff about encoding for an hour and I accidentally removed the INT in the statement. I thought it was still the encoding problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  CREATE TABLE `foo`(  
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `barbaz` VARCHAR(50) CHARSET utf8,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```